# How to send authorized request

Tags: asp.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, request

I send programatically a request to remote server:

string xml = "SomeXML Data";

```
string url = @"http://someserver.com";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "Post";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

//The encoding might have to be chaged based on requirement
UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(xml); //postbody is plain string of xml
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
reqStream.Close();
System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but this code throws error:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I know user/pass to autorize when IE ask me.

Could anyone help me how to send authorized request?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Login", "Password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Server seems to use Windows Authentication - although I am only guessing. If it is so, add this line:

```
   request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: how do you know it is windows Authentication?

Comment: I dont know. As I said, I am guessing... but it is very likely.

Comment: Guys webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Login", "Password"); 
works but only when I debug and some time pass, if i run the page without debugger, remote server throws error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the server is using windows integrated security?

try something like this

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(tokenUri);
req.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```